# Excel 2013: Count the occurrence of numbers/strings in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate how many time any given numbers appeared in an excel cell.

Conditions below:

- Each cell can have different combination of repetitive numbers, separated by commas.
- The excel formula will be robust enough to search for any numbers desired by user.
- Max range up to 20.

Example, I would input any number and the formula should return me a sum of occurrence.

---

```
1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 11, 1, 11
=>  5 (input "1" and "11")
=>  3 (input "1" only)
=>  2 (input "11" only)
*****************************************************
```

Things i have tried:

1. `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"1,",""))`  => Answer is 7 (wrong)
2. `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"1",""))`   => Answer is 8 (wrong)

Main difficulty:
The formula seems to search for "1" and therefore "11" would often mistooken as "1" too, and thus added to the sum.

Same goes for "5", "15" etc, any numbers in the tenths.

My approach was to do a text search instead of numbers, that failed.

Appreciate if there are alternate solutions too (Text -> Column ??).

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the delimiters front and back. This means that you also have to add them as a prefix and suffix to the original string.

```
=(LEN(", "&A2&", ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(", "&A2&", "),", 1,", "")))/LEN(", 1,")
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.
This works great. 
I will re-modify this line to search for the occurrence of 2 different numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If VBA is feasible, add this to VBA code and use the following function (assuming your long string is in cell A2)

```
= getOccurence(A2,5)
```

VBA Code:

```
Function getOccurence(inputString As String, numberToSearch As Integer) As Integer
        Dim strArray() As String
        strArray = Split(inputString, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
            If (strArray(i) = numberToSearch) Then
                getOccurence = getOccurence + 1
                End If
                Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Danielle but VBA is out of my league for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use text to columns to get each number in its own cell.  NOTE: you may want to insert blank columns to hold the numbers first so that you do not overwrite any data!

After this, I would use the function COUNTIF to count the number of occurrences of a certain number there is within a range.  For example:

=COUNTIF(F5:I5,2)+COUNTIF(F5:I5,3)

This counts the number of 2's and 3's within the range F5:I5

For more on this, see:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function

Comment: Thanks for the advise.
Have not thought of CountIf, worth a try.